# Keep symbol and text on same line?

Tags: html, css

I've got this and it's not working

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  background: #9f7a2b;
  color: white;
}

span.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span.title {
  font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif', georgia;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="./images/3d-graph-model.png" style="padding: 15px 0px 22px 0px" alt="3-d graph" class="center">
  <span class="nowrap">&#8728;<span class="title">My Title</span></span>
  <p>My supercool header</p>
</div>
```

I want the circle symbol and the "My Title" text on the same line, but the symbol tight, not spaced at the beginning of the line. Now I get the symbol above the title line. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `display: block;` property to the `span.title` element. As the result, the element is stretched to full available width. You can use a following code to solve your problem.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #9f7a2b;
  color: white;
}

span.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span.title {
  font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif', georgia;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="./images/3d-graph-model.png" style="padding: 15px 0px 22px 0px" alt="3-d graph" class="center">
  <span class="nowrap">&#8728;<span class="title">My Title</span></span>
  <p>My supercool header</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your problem using **display: flex; and align-items: center;** Then the content will show inline... here are my code check it hope it will help you :)

```css
    .header {
      text-align: center;
      background: #9f7a2b;
      color: white;
    }
    
    span.nowrap {
      white-space: nowrap;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    span.title {
      font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif', georgia;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: .4em;
      font-size: 2.3rem;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <img src="./images/3d-graph-model.png" style="padding: 15px 0px 22px 0px" alt="3-d graph" class="center">
      <span class="nowrap">&#8728;<span class="title">My Title</span></span>
      <p>My supercool header</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`<span class="nowrap">&#8728;<span class="title">My Title</span></span>`

by

`<div class="title"><span class="symbol">&#8728;</span>My Title</div>`.

Look the following code:

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  background: #9f7a2b;
  color: white;
}
.symbol {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif', georgia;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="./images/3d-graph-model.png" style="padding: 15px 0px 22px 0px" alt="3-d graph" class="center">
  <div class="title"><span class="symbol">&#8728;</span>My Title</div>
  <p>My supercool header</p>
</div>
```